# Generic JavaScript Models using Composition

Tags: javascript, node.js, composition

I am currently working on a Node.js application with a couple of JavaScript model like this:

```
function Role(data) {
  this.data = data;
  ...
}

Role.prototype.save = function(...) {...}

Role.findById = function(...) {...}
Role.findAll = function(...) {...}
```

All of them are using the same (similar) logic for most of the functions, but some need a different implementation for saving and so on. So my idea was to refactor them by using some kind of composition. My current solution is a combination of using inheritance for the prototype functions and an Adapter for the static functions. It looks like this.

```
var _adapter = new DatabaseAdapter(SCHEMA, TABLE, Role);

function Role(data) {
  Model.call(this, _adapter, Role._attributes)
  this.data = data;
  ...
}

Role._attributes = {
  name: ''
}

Role.prototype.save = function(...) {...}

Role.findById = function(...) {
  _adapter.findById(...);
}

Role.findAll = function(...)
{
  _adapter.findAll(...)
}
```

But, I am not really happy with my current solution, because the developers need to know a lot of implementation details to create a new Model. So, I hope someone could show me a better approach to solve my problem.

Thanks,
Hendrik

**Edit**
After some research I came up with the following solution:

Role model:

```
 Role.schema = 'db-schema-name';
 Role.table = 'db-table-name';
 Role.attributes = { /* attributes of the model */ }

 Role.prototype.save = genericSaveFunc;

 Role.findById = genericFindByIdFunc;
 ...
```

generic save:

```
 function genericSaveFunc(...) {
   if (this.id) {
     // handle update
     // attributes in 'this' will be updated 
   } else {
     // handle create
     // attributes in 'this' will be updated 
   }
 }
```

static generic function findById:

```
 function genericFindByIdFunc(...) {
   /* use this.schema && this.table to create correct SELECT statement */
 }
```

The model creation could be wrapped into a factory function. The good part of this solution is the simple creation of new models with different kind of functionality (e.g only add `save` and `findById` to a model). But I don't know if it is a good idea to rely on the calling context of the generic functions?

Answer (score 1):

Since your using a prototype-based language. There is no need to try to do class-inheritance. Take a look at [stampit](https://github.com/stampit-org/stampit) it will make it very easy for you to do composition the JavaScript way :)

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to stampit and thus also to Eric Elliotts posts about composition, but I would like to come up with a simple solution without using another library.